# 32 and 64 bit interoperability on 64-bit Windows

Tags: com, interop, ms-office

Is there a good thorough authoritative reference that discusses interoperability between 32-bit and 64-bit processes? Based on googling I have deduced that:

1. A 32-bit DLL can only reside in a 32-bit process, and a 64-bit DLL only in a 64-bit process.
2. 32 and 64-bit processes can only communicate using loosely coupled message systems, such as network communications, which means they can communicate using COM/DCOM.
3. 32 and 64-bit COM components have different registry entries. A component is typically only registered in one of the two and typically only seen in one of the two worlds.
4. A 32-bit process can only create something registered as a 64-bit COM component if it uses CoCreateInstance with the 64-bit invocation flag, or (and I am guessing on this one, is it possible?) if the 64-bit component is somehow registered in the 32-bit registry but under the hood is still created as an out of process 64-bit process, or if there is a 32-bit shell COM component which creates the 64-bit component and then redirects calls to it?

This suggests that:
1. A 32-bit application can not use GetObject to get hold of a 64-bit version of Excel that is running? Or can it? How is the running object table (ROT) impacted by 32 versus 64-bit issue? Can a 32-bit process create an instance of Excel if only a 64-bit version of Office is installed? I would think the answer would be "no" unless the 32-bit process uses the 64-bit flag in its CoCreateInstance call, or if Excel somehow registered itself in the 32-bit world as well?

Does Microsoft automatically do anything like having CoCreateInstance from a 32-bit process check the 64-bit registry and try to create an out of process 64-bit component if there is none registered in the 32-bit registry? I have seen some release notes from 64-bit Office where Microsoft warns about access from 32-bit applications to 64-bit Excel not working, yet I know of one instance where it seemed to just work.

Is there a good technical factual reference for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is explained quite well in the [MSDN Library docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms693716%28VS.85%29.aspx) for CLSCTX.  Lots of rules, the default behavior is:

> If neither the client nor the server
>   specifies a preference, then:
>
> - If the computer that hosts the server is running Windows XP or
>     Windows Server 2003 without Service
>     Pack 1 (SP1) or later installed, then
>     COM will prefer a 64-bit version of
>     the server if available; otherwise it
>     will activate a 32-bit version of the
>     server.
> - If the computer that hosts the server is running Windows Server 2003
>     with SP1 or later installed, then COM
>     will try to match the server
>     architecture to the client
>     architecture. In other words, for a
>     32-bit client, COM will activate a
>     32-bit server if available; otherwise
>     it will activate a 64-bit version of
>     the server. For a 64-bit client, COM
>     will activate a 64-bit server if
>     available; otherwise it will activate
>     a 32-bit server.

Check the MSDN article if you want to override this behavior.

Comment: Thank you, I had underestimated that MSDN section. Why then does this article http://www.dnjonline.com/article.aspx?id=jun07_access3264 create a 64-bit COM wrapper which simply interacts with the 32-bit COM one? That should be unnecessary, as having only the 32-bit COM component, should be equally usable from both 32 and 64-bit worlds assuming suitable marshalling of the functions and such? Also look at http://blogs.technet.com/b/office2010/archive/2010/02/23/understanding-64-bit-office.aspx, the bottom "what you should know" which warns about incompatibilities. Why?

Comment: The DDJ article focuses on making 32-bit COM servers work in a 64-bit process, the wrapper has to be 64-bit.  The Office article warns about incompatibilities for *in-process* COM servers.  Only out-of-process servers can bridge the gap.

Comment: The first article in the first comment has moved to http://blog.mattmags.com/2007/06/30/accessing-32-bit-dlls-from-64-bit-code/